# Почему json_encode преобразует UTF-8 символы

Tags: php, json

Столкнулся с любопытным вопросом. По умолчанию json_encode шифрует utf8 символы в \u* и чтобы это отключить необходимо использовать опцию JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE. Но почему это "экранирование" работает по умолчанию? Чему это помогает? И что правильнее делать для REST API для мобильных клиентов? Экранировать или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.  The default
>      encoding is UTF-8, and JSON texts that are encoded in UTF-8 are
>      interoperable in the sense that they will be read successfully by the
>      maximum number of implementations; there are many implementations
>      that cannot successfully read texts in other encodings (such as
>      UTF-16 and UTF-32).

Говорит нам стандарт [RFC7159](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc7159.html) 8.1. UTF-8 кодировка максимально гибкая и имеет такое свойство как `Interoperability`, что означает **максимально** адаптирован к работе, что приводит к **максимальному** количеству реализаций(`Implementations`). Существует много разных реализаций, которые не могут успешно и правильно прочитать текст, отправляемый в `JSON` формате(Такие как `UTF-16`, `UTF-32`).

Простым языком, `UTF-8` - в большинстве принята за кодировку, через которую могут общаться различные "объекты". Можно ее сравнить с английским языком. Это некий "интерациональный язык" общения, который можно использовать практически везде, и практически везде вас поймут и ответят на том же языке - в этом и заключается `Interoperability`.

Comment: А причем здесь UTF-16, 32. Если используется исключительно UTF-8. В общем суть в том что юникод везде разный и на \u* это приводится к единому формату?

Comment: Да, все верно :)